# Div is hiding after jquery fadeIn() has fully faded in

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm trying to fade in the index page when it is loaded (different fade in times for different content).

Most of them were working until I added 3 new divs, the new divs fade in correctly but once they are faded in to 100% opacity they then hide and do not show.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container').hide().fadeIn(2000);
    $('#topbar').hide().fadeIn(3000);
    $('#bg').hide().fadeIn(2000);
    $('.home-container').hide().fadeIn(4000);
});
```

The class marked 'home-container' is the container that hides after loading. I can't understand why it is doing this?

Comment: can you confirm that your `home-container` is having styles like `display:none;`? there could be issue with your css and document structure like `overflow:hidden;` and width calculations etc.

Comment: @Jai Thanks, there was a problem with my width and positioning, didn't think of that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove your `.hide()` before every fadeIn and simply add a css class with either `opacity: 0` or `display: none`;

```
.container { display: none; }
#topbar { display: none; }
#bg { display: none; }
.home-container { display: none; }
```

and the jQuery as following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container').fadeIn(2000);
    $('#topbar').fadeIn(3000);
    $('#bg').fadeIn(2000);
    $('.home-container').fadeIn(4000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this along with some positioning was the problem! :)

Comment: nice, if this answer helped you, please upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the hidden state form the css and fadeIn the divs on load:

CSS:

```
#yourElement { display: none }
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('#yourElement').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Using the method like that means to load something, not to wait for the onload event.

Comment: It just waits for window to load and then fades the hidden div